# How to serialize entire XML document into JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a html document which loads an XML document using jQuery

```
jQuery.ajax( {
    type: "GET",
    url: example.xml,
etc...
```

When that XML is loaded I want to serialize the entire XML document into a JavaScript array.

How would I do this?

Comment: And the serialized array should look like what?

Comment: I want the XML literally to be directly input into the array, as is. Basically making a copy of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
jQuery.ajax( {
    type: "GET",
    url: "example.xml",
    success: function(data) {
        var results = [];
        // This bit varies depending on your XML structure, but you get the idea
        $(data).find('your_element').each(function(){
            results.push($(this));
        });
    }
 });
```